# How can be represented a linear map as a matrix with respect to a direct sum?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $E$ be a finite-dimensional vector space and $B : E \to E$ a linear isomorphism.
Can someone explain me how can be represented $B$ as a matrix with respect to the direct sum $E = E_1 \bigoplus E_2$?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any linear map on the direct sum of two vector spaces is the same as a pair of linear maps, one component per summand. Thus $B$ "is" a linear map $B_1\colon E_1\to E$ together with a linear map $B_2\colon E_2\to E$.
Likewise, any linear map to a direct sum of two vector spaces is the same as a pair of linear maps, one component per summand. Thus in total $B$ is given by four linear maps $B_{i,j}\colon E_i\to E_j$, $1\le i,j\le 2$. You may arrange these in a $2\times 2$ matrix as $B=\begin{pmatrix}B_{1,1}&B_{1,2}\\B_{2,1}&B_{2,2}\end{pmatrix}$.